# adding data from gridview to a session variable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, gridview

I have a gridView with entries, a book title and and image.

How can I add the selecteted index book title and imageUrl respectively to session variables upon the buttonField click event so that I can use this information on a different page.

I would think something like

```
string title = (string)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].DataItem["Title"];
        Session["Title"] = title;
        Response.Redirect("RateBook.aspx");
```

The above code is not correct. How do I actually select and individual item in the selected row and add it to the variable upon the button click event?

Reagards

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this in your Row Command Event of your Gridview. like...

Suppose your Button CommandName is **StoreValue** but you set whatever

```
if(e.CommandName == "StoreValue")
{
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
  string title = row.Cells[ColumnIndex].Text;

    Session["Title"] = title;
    Response.Redirect("RateBook.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
string title = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].text;
Session["Title"] = title;
Response.Redirect("RateBook.aspx");
```

replace the "ColumnIndex" parameter with the number of the "Title" column.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the complete example.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" Text="Select" runat="server" 
            onclick="btnSelect_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grdTest.DataSource = Book.Books;
            grdTest.DataBind();
        }


    }
    protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = false;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdTest.Rows)
        {
            result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
            if (result)
            {
                Session["Title"] = row.Cells[1].Text;
                Session["Author"] = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public static List<Book> Books
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Book>()
                       {
                           new Book{Title = "Title1",Author = "Author1"},
                           new Book{Title = "Title2",Author = "Author2"},
                           new Book{Title = "Title3",Author = "Author3"},

                       };
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its working for me

```
 protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {        
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridVIew1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex == GridVIew1.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
                        row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
                        row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
                    }
                }
                //suppose your index is in cell[0]//
                Session["Index"] = GridVIew1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

// you can get details by index using this session //